# xinetd doesn't read "included directory"

Tags: pfsense, xinetd

I want to monitor my pfSense-Box with check_mk. Therefore I need access to a certain port via xinetd. I found a descripton for that in:
https://forum.netgate.com/topic/99612/pfsense-2-3-check_mk-working-with-xinetd/2

After reloading filters, I get following in Status | System logs | General:

> Unable to read included directory: /opt/etc/xinetd.d [file=/var/etc/xinetd.conf] [line=1]

/var/etc/xinetd.conf contains:

```
includedir /opt/etc/xinetd.d
```

/opt/etc/xinet.d has rights set to 775:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 root  wheel  512 Dec  6 15:36 xinet.d
```

The file /opt/etc/xinetd/check_mk is from above post. The important part is:

```
service check_mk
{
    type           = UNLISTED
    port           = 6556
    socket_type    = stream
    protocol       = tcp
    wait           = no
    user           = root
    server         = /opt/bin/check_mk_agent
    #server         = /usr/bin/check_mk_caching_agent
    # configure the IP address(es) of your Nagios server here:
    only_from      = 127.0.0.1 192.168.129.12 192.168.129.33
    log_on_success =
    disable        = no
}
```

So to me everything looks fine, but since the xinetd-rule is not beeing loaded, I can't connect to the check_mk_agent from my monitoring-server.

Looking even deeper in it, I found that the line

```
fclose($xinted_fd);
```

is twice in the file '/etc/inc/filter.inc' - in line 2256 and in 2479. I added the line to include '/opt/etc/xinetd.d' before both of them. Nothing changed after reloading the filter. There are the same error-messages in the log.

When I start xinetd by hand with

```
xinetd -f /var/etc/xinetd.conf
```

it starts and I can get my checks from the monitor-host. After rebooting, xinetd is not running any more :-((

Comment: Thank you Gerald for formating my question - I really tried my best, following the instructions, but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I had an, invisible, character in the name of the directory. Deleting it and creating again (typing carefully) made it work.
I'm very sorry for taking your time.
Karl